# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm getting the error:
Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read()
at:  string result = Reader.GetString(0);

I'm not entirely sure what to do or whats wrong though

```
internal int GetCharGuidByName(string charactername, MySqlConnection connection)
{
    MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    MySqlDataReader Reader;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT guid FROM characters WHERE name=\""+charactername+"\";";
    // Initialize MySQL Reader
    Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    Reader.Read();
    string result = Reader.GetString(0);
    // If the character doesn't exist or isn't entered, return 0
    int charguid = 0;
    if (result != String.Empty)
    {
        charguid = Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }
    return charguid;
}
```

Comment: Have you opened a connection before asigning reader to command.ExecuteReader method? And change Reader.Read() to if(Reader.Read()){...} , and if there is no result to read, code will not go into if statement.

Comment: Yeah, the connection is open, also tried creating a connection within this function (not using the one received by the function) and opening it and it does the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
int charguid = 0;
if(Reader.Read())
{
   if(Reader[0] != DBNull.Value)
   {
       if(int.TryParse(Reader[0].ToString(), out charguid))
       {
        //value read and is an integer!
       }
   }
}
return charguid;
```

Comment: I'm getting two errors: The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments, and Argument 2: cannot convert from 'out int' to 'System.IFormatProvider' from this code

Answer (score 1):

You should use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader

> ExecuteSaclar returns the first column of the first row in the result
>   set, or a null reference
>
> ExecuteReader will return as resultset which you have to then iterate
>   to read

So looking at your code you just want the first column of the result set

```
internal int GetCharGuidByName(string charactername, MySqlConnection connection)
{
    int charguid = 0;

    using(MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
      command.CommandText = "SELECT guid FROM characters WHERE name=\""+charactername+"\";";
      object obj  = command.ExecuteScalar();
      if (obj != null && obj != DBNull.Value)
      {
         charguid = Convert.ToInt32(obj);
      }
    }

      return charguid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            openConnection()

            sql = "SELECT last, first, emp_type, active FROM employee INNER JOIN account ON employee.emp_id = account.emp_id WHERE employee.emp_id = '" & AtxtEmpID.Text & "'"

            command = New MySqlCommand(sql, mySqlConnection)

            reader = command.ExecuteReader

            reader.Read()

            AtxtEmpName.Text = reader.Item(0) & ", " & reader.Item(1)

            closeConn()
```

have the save problem